# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' error

Tags: python, module, pip, pycharm, python-imaging-library

To use the pillow module I wrote down the command:

pip install pillow

And in the file to use I wrote:

from PIL import Image

But I get the error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

what can I do?

Comment: I'm running in Pycharm

Comment: Where did you do the pip install, make sure that the install happened in your virtual environment. I think the pycharm interpreter is pointing somewhere else.

Comment: @NYCCoder Thank you! That solved the problem!

Answer (score -1):

Install pillow by writing pip install Pillow in your terminal. (P in Pillow is capitalised )
Then you can call the image library using: from PIL import Image (PIL in all capital and Image is capitalised)

Comment: i got error : failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- install-u3857bsp\Pillow\

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).